# Cannot vertically align the two div tags in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make two div tags side by side each other and make it vertically align. For some reason, I'm having trouble verticalling aligning it. I have used float element to make the city and postal code div side by side, but for an unknown reason the postal code is a bit higher than the city div..
I tried adjusting it with margin-top and margin-bottom, but it still would not move. It seems like it's stuck and I'm not sure exactly what the problem is..

```css
body {
  background-color: #EFF9F0;
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
  color: #F8F8F8;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
}

#back {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 33%;
  width: 95px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4F772D;
  color: white;
}

#posting-title {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

#posting-title-form {
  width: 80%;
}

#city {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

#city-total {
  float: left;
}

#postal-total {
  margin-right: 15%;
}

#postal-code-form {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <button id="back">Back</button>
</div>
<div id="posting-title">
  <p id="posting-paragraph">
    posting title
  </p>
  <input type="text" id="posting-title-form">
</div>

<div id="city">
  <div id="city-total">
    <p id="city-title">
      city/neighbourhood
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="posting-city-form">
  </div>

  <div id="postal-total">
    <p id="postal-code-title">
      postal code
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="postal-code-form">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kohansalism/7k3de546/

Comment: Some changes in your CSS